# iPod Dock Charge Adapter

Tags: ipod, charge

I have a nice stereo system that can dock and charge an iPod Nano 2nd generation.

I also have an iPod Touch 4 and a 6th gen Nano (or something).

The old docks charge using the firewire pin out and the new ones with the USB power pin out (if I understand correctly).

my google-fu is failing to find a dock adapter that will swap the pinout so I can dock my newere nano into the older dock and play and charge. (It plays now but won't charge)

Is anyone aware of such a product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Charging Adapter from Scosche](http://www.scosche.com/consumer-tech/product/1667) should work for you. I used one of these in a car that had a iPod dock for the radio, but used the older Firewire pinout, and therefore would not work well with a newer iPhone.

This one looks slightly different than the one I had, but it should be the same thing. Griffin I think also makes a similar product. Its a common problem for car radios, so maybe searching for that will help find similar products.

**Update**: The [Scosche Passport](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001HN6CVA) is what we actually have. This worked great connecting a newer nano, iPhone 4 and 4S to a Firewire charging deck.